# Nested for loop indexing issue in R

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I'm having an issue with properly indexing a for loop. I have a data set `platform_datatest` which is `j` rows long and corresponds to `j` candidates. Each candidate has 30 platforms or `i`. I am trying to convert this from a wide dataset to long where I have each platform as a separate row with the candidate's name (and other info) there, so I it is `j*i` rows long. I am able to get out each candidate's information correctly as well as their platform information, but indexing this correctly so rows 1-30 are candidate 1, 31-60 are candidate 2, etc. is proving to be a pain (k maybe?) I tried triple nesting but wasn't working. Any suggestions?

```
#empty data set
platform_settest <- data.frame(name = rep(NA, length = 60),
                                state = rep(NA, length = 60), 
                                year = rep(NA, length = 60),
                                topic = rep(NA, length = 60),
                                title = rep(NA, length = 60),
                                text = rep(NA, length = 60))


for (j in 1:nrow(platform_datatest)){ #number of candidates
      
      for(i in 1:30){ #number of issue positions
        
        
        name <- platform_datatest[j, 1]
        state <- platform_datatest[j, 3]
        year <- platform_datatest[j, 4]
        
        
        topic <- paste0("Q24A.1_", i)
        title <- paste0("Q24A.2_", i, "_1")
        text <- paste0("Q24A.3_", i, "_1")
        
        k <- ??
      
        platform_settest[k, 1] <- name
        platform_settest[k, 2] <- state
        platform_settest[k, 3] <- year
        platform_settest[k, 4] <- platform_datatest[j, topic]
        platform_settest[k, 5] <- platform_datatest[j, title]
        platform_settest[k, 6] <- platform_datatest[j, text]
      
      }}
```

Comment: I feel you don't need a loop for your goal but it is hard to say without seeing your expected output. So, Can you edit your question with your expected output?

Comment: `k` should be something like `30 * (i - 1) + j`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does what you are looking for?!

```
library(tidyverse)

platform_settest <- data.frame(name = rep(NA, length = 60),
                               state = rep(NA, length = 60), 
                               year = rep(NA, length = 60),
                               topic = rep(NA, length = 60),
                               title = rep(NA, length = 60),
                               text = rep(NA, length = 60))

platform_settest <- 
  platform_settest |> 
  mutate(topic = paste0("Q24A.1_", 1:nrow(platform_settest)),
         title = paste0("Q24A.2_", 1:nrow(platform_settest)),
         text = paste0("Q24A.3_", 1:nrow(platform_settest))) 

pivot_longer(platform_settest,
               cols = c(topic, title, text),  
               names_to = "ttt")
#> # A tibble: 180 × 5
#>    name  state year  ttt   value   
#>    <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr> <chr>   
#>  1 NA    NA    NA    topic Q24A.1_1
#>  2 NA    NA    NA    title Q24A.2_1
#>  3 NA    NA    NA    text  Q24A.3_1
#>  4 NA    NA    NA    topic Q24A.1_2
#>  5 NA    NA    NA    title Q24A.2_2
#>  6 NA    NA    NA    text  Q24A.3_2
#>  7 NA    NA    NA    topic Q24A.1_3
#>  8 NA    NA    NA    title Q24A.2_3
#>  9 NA    NA    NA    text  Q24A.3_3
#> 10 NA    NA    NA    topic Q24A.1_4
#> # … with 170 more rows
```